# How to use php with soap web service on heroku

Tags: php, heroku, salesforce

We are using soap client library in our application to fetch `Salesforce` data using API in PHP.

When we run simple php page it runs properly but not with soap client.

We run this command and getting error as shown below

```
$ heroku run php www/sandbox/index-test.php
Running `php www/sandbox/index-test.php` attached to terminal... up, run.1586
```

**PHP Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'soapclient/enterprise.wsdl.xml' : failed to load external entity "soapclient/enterprise.wsdl.xml" in /app/www/sandbox/soapclient/SforceBaseClient.php on line 64**

Comment: Well, it seems to be looking for a file that does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using xml path as 'soapclient/enterprise.wsdl.xml', this needs full path for the xml file 'http://domain.com/soapclient/enterprise.wsdl.xml'