# Heroku + Lumen SoapClient

Tags: php, heroku, lumen

I'm developing an app with Lumen Framework which needs to use SoapClient to communicate with Magaya Software. My app is hosted in Heroku, and has been worked well for few months. 3 days ago I realized that quotations transactions with magaya were failing. I tested the endpoint with postman and I get

> '500 Internal Server Error Class SoapClient not found.'

From my localhost is Ok, I can send a quotation without any errors.

magayaApi.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;
use \SoapClient;

class MagayaAPI extends \SoapClient implements MagayaAPIInterface
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/lumen",
    "description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "ext-bcmath": "*",
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.9.0",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "^8.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3",
        "tibonilab/pdf-lumen-bundle": "~2.0.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ]
    }
}
```

Heroku host phpinfo show SoapClient is not active

I tried to add in composer.json

```
"classmap": [ "soapclient"]
```

and

```
"require": {
        "ext-soap": "*"
    }
```

Regenerate composer.lock, but obtain same results
I found some related posts

1. [How to use php with soap web service on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130010/how-to-use-php-with-soap-web-service-on-heroku)
2. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80811/class-not-found-with-php-app-hosted-on-heroku

But I can't solve my problem yet. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

composer.json

```
"require": {
        "ext-soap": "*"
    }
```

I regenerated composer.lock, upload my changes and now is working. Must to be I missed something before.
Sorry for wasted time